# "git does not appear to be a git repository" after remote server changes IP address

Tags: git

The git repository is hosted on the shared drive mounted to Linux Ubuntu. The IP address of the shared drive has changed and the environmental variable  (host) has been updated accordingly. However, when push to the shard drive, I got "does not appear to be a git repository' error. Is there any reason for this and how to fix it? Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. IP is not hardcoded. However, I found the remote url path is the problem. I changed the remote url from "shared/backupfiles.git" to: "shared/git/repositories/backupfiles.git". It works again.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that your local git repo uses a hardcoded IP instead of the environment variable. Run `git remote -v` to see if that is the case. If it is, then run `git remote set-url <URL>` to change it to the environment variable.